# How to use Mysql Max function properly

Tags: mysql

I have the following Mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    pr.`datum`, SUM(pt.`db`) AS darabszam 
FROM 
    prendeles pr
JOIN
    ptetel pt ON pr.`razon`=pt.`razon`
GROUP BY 
    pr.`datum` 
HAVING 
    darabszam = (SELECT MAX(SUM(pt.`db`) FROM prendeles)
```

I would like to list those "pr.datum" field (as result only 1 record) where the SUM(pt.`db`) is the max in the column, but unfortunately my code does not work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: SQLyog give the following error: "Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM prendeles)
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 3"

Comment: Even if there was some logic behind MAX(SUM()), it still wouldn't work.

Comment: that is why i am asking for help to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have a suggestion.

Instead of testing whether the SUM is also the MAX (which, by the way, also means that the SUM is the MIN), why not test whether the COUNT within your desired grouping is 1?

Then again, after having said this, I see you coded MAX( SUM(  ) )--which isn't even legal syntax--so one can only guess what you're truly aiming for.

Comment: actualy in the "SUM(pt.`db`)" colunb i have multiple results (i have summed some numeric values) and i want to find out which is the largest value among these nembers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this:

```
select pr.datum, SUM(pt.db) as darabszam from prendeles pr JOIN ptetel pt ON pr.razon=pt.razon group by pr.datum HAVING MAX(darabszam) from prendreles
```

Since `darabszam` is an Alias for SUM(pt.db).

Comment: Tryed is, SQLyog says is is invalid expression for "darabszam"